# How to print for loop table of multiplication?

Tags: c#

How would I print number till 20.

```
for (int a = 2; a <= 20; a += 2)
{
     Console.WriteLine("2x1= {0} ", a);
}
```

for example:

```
2x1= 2
2x2= 4
2x3= 6
2x4= 8
2x5= 10
2x6= 12
2x7= 14
2x8= 16
2x9= 18
2x10= 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate your `a` from `1` to `10` and print it in your multiplication and it's result.

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("2x{0} = {1}", a, a * 2);
}
```

Here a <kbd>[**demo**](http://ideone.com/lhkYRi)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You may also iterate `a` from 1-10 and use the [left bit shift operator (<<)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx):

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2x{0} = {1}", a, a << 1);
}
```

C#-6 version:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"2x{a} = {a << 1}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string.Format is a very useful function for printing/formatting this kind of statements. Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)